# pandas interpolate on new time base

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I'm looking for an easy way to put two dataframe with a physical seconds index on a new timebase using interpolation, e.g. with the example data

```py
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'time': np.arange(2, 300, 0.2),
                      'data': np.random.randint(0, 2, len(np.arange(2, 300, 0.2)))
                      }).set_index('time')

data2 = pd.DataFrame({'time': np.arange(10, 260, 0.2),
                      'data': np.random.randint(0, 2, len(np.arange(10, 260, 0.2)))
                      }).set_index('time')

new_timebase = np.linspace(10, 250, 2400)
```

I want to have both dataframes `data1` and `data2` have new_timebase (as index) with values interpolated from the original frames. In this case, since the data is `int`, a *nearest* intepolation would be preferable, else a subsequent call to `round()` would also be an option.

The final goal is to have a meaningful way of *binary and* the status in `data1 & data2`

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use [DatetimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) and [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample)?

Comment: Pandas has [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html?highlight=pa) with `direction='nearest'` option.

Comment: @philipphutterer im not that good with pandas and got only seconds (as float, with microseconds) and don’t know how to convert that but I will take a look